# How do I disable Google Apps contact sharing outside the organization?

Tags: google-workspace

I want to prevent users in my org from allowing outside apps (e.g., LinkedIn) from accessing/managing user contact list. How do I set that up? I don't see such an option in the App Console under contact sharing settings. Those settings just seem to deal with sharing contacts with other users inside the org.